# derivative of cosine similarity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

What is derivative of cosine similarity between two vectors?

I found a paper that refers the derivative of cosine similarity  ($\cos=\frac{v_i\cdot{v_j}}{|v_i||v_j|}$) is as below.

$$
\frac{\partial{\cos}}{\partial{v_i}}=\frac{\cos\cdot{v_i}}{\left|v_i\right|^2}+\frac{v_j}{\left|v_i\right|\left|v_j\right|}.
$$

There's no detailed explanation in the paper and I couldn't find any derivation of the derivative in internet.

Is the derivation correct? 
If it's correct, how the derivative is found?

Comment: refer to the answer to [the related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923613)