# Derivation of the derivative of Cosine Similarity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-spaces, partial-derivative

$$
\cos (\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}) = \frac{{\langle\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\rangle}}
{{|| {\mathbf{v} } ||\;|| \mathbf{w}||}}
$$

where $\langle\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\rangle$ is the dot product, and $||\cdot||$ is the second norm.

Like [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923613/partial-derivative-of-cosine-similarity) did,  we can add a little $d\mathbf{v}$ to $\mathbf{v}$:

$$
\frac{{\langle\mathbf{v}+d\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\rangle}}{{|| {\mathbf{v}+d\mathbf{v} } ||\;|| \mathbf{w}||}}
$$

However, suppose
$$
|| {\mathbf{v}+d\mathbf{v} }|| = \sqrt{f(\mathbf{v})}
$$
then,
$$
f(\mathbf{v})=( \mathbf{v}+d\mathbf{v} )^T( \mathbf{v}+d\mathbf{v} )= \mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{v}+d\mathbf{v} ^T\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{v}^T d\mathbf{v}+d\mathbf{v}^T d\mathbf{v}
\\=||\mathbf{v}||^2+||d\mathbf{v}||^2+d\mathbf{v} ^T\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{v}^T d\mathbf{v}
$$
So basically,
$$
|| {\mathbf{v}+d\mathbf{v} }|| = \sqrt{||\mathbf{v}||^2+||d\mathbf{v}||^2+d\mathbf{v} ^T\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{v}^T d\mathbf{v}}
$$
I don't see why this equals/approxiametely equals
$$
|| {\mathbf{v}+d\mathbf{v} }||\approx|| \mathbf{v} ||\left( {1 + \frac{\mathbf{v}}
{{|| \mathbf{v} ||^2 }} \cdot d\mathbf{v}} \right) ?
$$
Particularly, if $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{u}$ are complex, I think there is a problem, no?

Can anyone gieve some suggestions/hint here? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factoring out $\|\vec{v}\|$ from inside the square root, and using symmetry of the dot product, gives you
$$
\|\vec{v}+d\vec{v}\|=\|\vec{v}\|\sqrt{1+\frac{\|d\vec{v}\|^2}{\|\vec{v}\|^2}+2\frac{\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{v}}{\|\vec{v}\|^2}}.
$$
Considering $\vec{v}$ as being itself fixed, and $d\vec{v}\to\vec{0}$, we can think about asymptotics.  Note that
$$
\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}+O(x^2),\qquad x\to0,
$$
so that
$$
\sqrt{1+\frac{\|d\vec{v}\|^2}{\|\vec{v}\|^2}+2\frac{\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{v}}{\|\vec{v}\|^2}}=1+\frac{\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{v}}{\|\vec{v}\|^2}+O(\|d\vec{v}\|^2).
$$

Comment: Thakns Nick. I am wondering what if $v$ is complex? In that case $dv^Tv$ and $v^Tdv$ would not be equal, thus can not be combined to $ 2vdv$?

Comment: True enough; off the top, it would seem that it would replace $\vec{v}\cdot d\vec{v}$ by its real part.