# How do I get the derivatives of the square of cosine similarity?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

Let $\theta_i$ and $\theta_j$ are vectors with same length.(and there are $n$ vectors)

I define the *cost* function like below :

$$
C(\theta)=\frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n 
\sum_{\begin{smallmatrix} j=1 \\ j\neq i \end{smallmatrix}}^n \cos^2(\theta_i,\theta_j) = \frac12 \sum_{i=1}^n 
\sum_{\begin{smallmatrix} j=1 \\ j\neq i \end{smallmatrix}}^n
\Big(\frac{\left<\theta_i,\theta_j\right>}{\|\theta_i\|\|\theta_j\|}\Big)^2
$$
So, to use gradient decent I want to get the derivatives of the $C(\theta)$ with respect to the parameters $\theta$.

How do I get this?

Comment: What is $\theta$?

Comment: So are you implying $\theta = (\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3, \ldots)$ ?

Comment: Maybe this will help at least a bit: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923613/partial-derivative-of-cosine-similarity

Comment: @Matti P.  Yes. $\theta = (\theta_1, \theta_2, ...)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, collect the vectors into the columns of a single matrix
$$
X = \big[\,\theta_1\;\theta_2\;\ldots\;\theta_n\,\big] \in{\mathbb R}^{m\times n}
$$
Then form the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) and some auxiliary matrices
$$\eqalign{
G &= X^TX \implies dG = (X^TdX + dX^TX) \\
B &= {\rm Diag}(G) = I\odot G \\
L &= B^{-1/2} \implies B = L^{-2},\quad dB = -2L^{-3}dL \\
Y &= LGL \\
M &= GLY + YLG,\quad P=I\odot M \\
}$$
all of which are $n\times n,\,$ symmetric. Several of them $(B,L,P)$ are diagonal and these will be particularly nice to work with since they commute and their functions (e.g. square roots) are easy to calculate.

The symbol $\odot$ is the elementwise/Hadamard product and $I$ is the $(n\times n)$ identity matrix.

Write the cost function in terms of $Y$, then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
C &= \tfrac{1}{2}(Y:Y - n) \\
dC &= Y:dY \\
 &= Y:(L\,dG\,L + LG\,dL + dL\,GL) \\
 &= LYL:dG + M:dL \\
 &= LYL:dG - \tfrac{1}{2}M:L^3dB \\
 &= LYL:dG - \tfrac{1}{2}L^3M:(I\odot dG) \\
 &= \big(LYL - \tfrac{1}{2}(L^3M)\odot I\big):dG \\
 &= L\big(Y - \tfrac{1}{2}LP\big)L:(X^TdX + dX^TX) \\
 &= L\big(2Y - LP\big)L:X^TdX \\
 &= XL\big(2Y - LP\big)L:dX \\
\frac{\partial C}{\partial X} &= XL\big(2Y - LP\big)L \\
}$$
To find the gradient with respect to the $k^{th}$ column of $X$ (wrt $\theta_k$), multiply the above matrix-valued gradient by $e_k,\,$ the $k^{th}$ standard basis vector, to obtain
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial C}{\partial \theta_k} 
 &= \bigg(\frac{\partial C}{\partial X}\bigg)e_k
\;=\; XL\big(2Y - LP\big)Le_k \\
}$$
In several steps above, a colon is used to represent the trace/Frobenius product $\;A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$

The properties of the trace allow the terms in such products to be rearranged in lots of different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
A:BC &= B^TA:C = AC^T:B = etc \\
}$$
One last property is that Hadamard and Frobenius products commute
$$\eqalign{
A:(B\odot C) 
 &= (A\odot B):C \\
 &= (B\odot A):C \\
 &= C:(B\odot A) \\
}$$