# Partial derivative of the absolute difference between cosine similarity of two vectors and a scalar

Tags: partial-derivative

This [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923613/partial-derivative-of-cosine-similarity) develops the partial derivative of cosine similarity between two vectors.

Given a scalar $k$ and the cosine similarity function

$$cossim (\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}) = \frac{{\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{w}}}
{{\left| {\mathbf{v} } \right|\;\left| \mathbf{w} \right|}}$$

how can we find the following partial derivative?

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{\mathbf{v}}}|k - cossim(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})|$$

My attempt based on Andrew L's comment is as below. Is it correct?

$$y := k - cossim(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{v}}|y| = \frac{y}{|y|} \frac{\partial y}{\partial \mathbf{v}}
$$,

and from the accepted answer in above thread:

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial \mathbf{v}} =  - \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{v}} cossim(\mathbf{v},  \mathbf{w})
\\\ = - \frac{\mathbf{w}}{|\mathbf{v}|\cdot{|\mathbf{w}|}} + cossim(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})\cdot{\frac{\mathbf{v}}
{|\mathbf{v}|^2}}$$.

When put together, the solution is:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{v}}|k - cossim(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})| = \frac{k - cossim(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})}{|k - cossim(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})|} ( cossim(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})\cdot{\frac{\mathbf{v}}
{|\mathbf{v}|^2}} - \frac{\mathbf{w}}{|\mathbf{v}|\cdot{|\mathbf{w}|}}) $$

Comment: Question: what is $v$ in this case? If you mean a component of $\mathbf{v}$ you should specify that. Barring that, if $k$ is nothing more than a constant, then you can easily just use the chain rule. The derivative of $|x|$ isn't hard, it's just $\frac{d}{dx}|x|=\frac{x}{|x|}$, so by the chain rule, $\frac{d}{dx}|u|=\frac{u}{|u|}\frac{du}{dx}$

Comment: $v$ was a typing error and is now replaced with $\mathbf{v}$ in the original question. I also added an attempted solution based on your comment. Thank you.